# Making nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, nested

This was the question:

"Write a function, *find_all(L, i)*, that takes a nested list *L* and, an item *i* and, prints the indices of all occurrences of *i* in *L*.

What:

```
from string import *
def find_all(L,i):
    for sub_list in L:
        if i in sub_list:
            return (L.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(i))
print find_all([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]], 5)
```

The output was only (1,1).

Comment: Well, you're `return`ing as soon as you stumble upon the first valid result, which is obviously not what you need. Also, the title is misleading as you don't actually 'make' any nested lists.

Comment: Apart from the problem mentioned by ForceBru, you need to change your logic so that it handles duplicate sublists in L that contain `i`, or `i` being repeated in a sublist. Hint: if you use `enumerate` you won't need to do that inefficient `L.index(sub_list)` search.

Comment: What's the (invalid) `from string import` for?

Answer (score 1):

```
ll = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]]

def find_all(ll,num):
  for index_inner,inner_list in enumerate(ll):
    for index,item in enumerate(inner_list):
      if item == num:
        print('List :',inner_list,'List Index :',index_inner, 'Index :' ,index)

find_all(ll,5)
```

**RESULT**

```
List : [4, 5] List Index : 1 Index : 1
List : [5, 13] List Index : 3 Index : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `yield` instead of return.  Yield returns a generator expression that can then be converted over to a `list`.

```
def find_all(L,i):
    for sub_list in L:
        if i in sub_list:
            yield (L.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(i))
print list(find_all([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]], 5))
```

Alternatively, if you want to return a list by default, define a temporary return list.

```
def find_all(L,i):
    returnLi = []
    for sub_list in L:
        if i in sub_list:
            returnLi.append((L.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(i)))
    return returnLi
print find_all([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]], 5)
```

Finally, if you don't need a list or prefer not to use yield, you can simply print out results as you come to them:

```
def find_all(L,i):
    for sub_list in L:
        if i in sub_list:
            print((L.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(i)))
find_all([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]], 5)
```

Comment: `yield` may be a bit advanced for the OP. They don't need a list so they can print the results as they find them. Also see my 1st comment on the question.

Comment: @PM2Ring I added the extra option.  I think it'd be nice for the OP to learn something knew, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using return, it's terminating the program after finding the first result instead of continuing so do this:

```
def find_all(mylist, char):
    for sub_list in mylist:
        if char in sub_list:
            print ("({},{})".format(mylist.index(sub_list),sub_list.index(char)))

find_all([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[5,13]], 5)
```

Output:

```
(1 ,1)
(3, 0)
```

Comment: Edited it @PM2Ring

Comment: That works ok on the sample data, but see my 1st comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The return function in you loop exit the loop right away when `if i in sub_list:` satisfied.

To print all of them, just create a temp variable as list to store data, as following:

```
from string import *
temp = []
def find_all(L,i):
    for sub_list in L:
        if i in sub_list:
            temp.append([L.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(i)])
    return temp
```